# Invalid pathData. Failure occurred at position 65 in FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

I am getting an error but it is only on Android Nougat.

This is my **`fragment_main.xml`** that contains `FloatingActionButton`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnShowHomeMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/theme_yellow"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_main" />
```

This is my ic_menu_main.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="141dp"
        android:height="128dp"
        android:viewportWidth="141.4"
        android:viewportHeight="128.6">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#20000000"
        android:pathData="M141.4,68.32l-53.03,53.03a25,25 88.59,0 1,-35.36 0l-53.03,-53.03aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0l42.43,-42.43a40,40 0,0 1,56.57 -0l42.43,42.43ANaN,NaN NaN,0 1,141.4 68.32Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M141.38,58.29l-53.03,53.03a25,25 88.59,0 1,-35.36 0l-53.03,-53.03aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0l42.43,-42.43a40,40 0,0 1,56.57 -0l42.43,42.43ANaN,NaN NaN,0 1,141.38 58.29Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFffee61"
        android:pathData="M0,58.3l49.5,-49.5a30,30 0,0 1,42.4 0l49.5,49.5 -42.4,42.4a40,40 0,0 0,-56.6 0Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF515151"
        android:pathData="M84.89,75.27l-10.61,10.61a5,5 91.17,0 1,-7.07 0l-10.61,-10.61aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0l10.61,-10.61a5,5 91.17,0 1,7.07 -0l10.61,10.61ANaN,NaN NaN,0 1,84.89 75.27Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF515151"
        android:pathData="M84.82,42.3l-10.61,10.61a5,5 0,0 1,-7.07 0l-10.61,-10.61aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0l10.61,-10.61a5,5 0,0 1,7.07 -0l10.61,10.61ANaN,NaN NaN,0 1,84.82 42.3Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF515151"
        android:pathData="M67.83,58.27l-10.61,10.61a5,5 90.52,0 1,-7.07 0l-10.61,-10.61aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0l10.61,-10.61a5,5 0,0 1,7.07 -0l10.61,10.61ANaN,NaN NaN,0 1,67.83 58.27Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF515151"
        android:pathData="M100.89,59.29l-10.61,10.61a5,5 91.17,0 1,-7.07 0l-10.61,-10.61aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0l10.61,-10.61a5,5 0,0 1,7.07 -0l10.61,10.61aNaN,NaN NaN,0 1,0 0Z"/>
</vector>
```

I am not sure why it give invalid path data. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nan causes an error which is produced by the converter.
Just replace NaN with some random numbers and it works (try to make sure the number does not cause the vector to change)